# PHP code keeps inserting empy values into the database.

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to create this form and every time I try to create a dummy user it creates an empy one in the database.

Here's the php code **create.php**:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include ('connection.php');

  $username = $_POST['usernamesignup'];
  $email = $_POST['emailsignup'];
  $password = $_POST['passwordsignup'];

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (usernamesignup, passwordsignup, emailsignup) 
         VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')")or die (mysql_error());
  header('Location: login.html');
  mysql_close($db);
?>
```

And here's the part of the form **Login.html**:

```
<form  action="create.php" autocomplete="on"> 
  <h1> Sign up </h1> 
  <p><label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
  <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" /></p>
  <p><label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
  <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/></p>
  <p><label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
  <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/></p>
  <p><label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
  <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/></p>
  <p class="signin button"><input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
  <p class="change_link">Already a member?<a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a></p>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The adding of method:"post" did the trick. Thank you very much to all of you for your fast response and the very valid advises on security and on how I should change to a more current form instead of what I used here.

Comment: You should upgrade to a modern and supported database library. mysql_* is on the chopping block ... switch to mysqli or pdo

Comment: In addition to what @Orangepill said, **DO NOT** store your passwords in plain text like that. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: It is extremely hazardous to take `$_POST` data and inject it directly into your query string. Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you hurt yourself. This is a sign-up form on the internet, right? It would take *zero seconds* to hack this wide open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the values sent by your form are not null or with an empty string. And please be very careful your code is vulnerable to sql injections and hash your password in sha512 or something like that.

have a look to this function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

and try to add this in your form :

```
<form  action="create.php" autocomplete="on" method="post">
```

Comment: And please don't use mysql functions. Depreacted as of 5.5

Comment: Yeah, I'm just working on the basics idea to understand how it works and make it functional at its basic. The security measures will be taken by my CTO before going live, but thank you very much for pointing it out. Let me check about those null.

Comment: And change the form to method="post"

Comment: Work on the right basics then instead of learning all the out of date wrong and insecure basics, just learn the current secure basics which are not really any more complex than the old stuff

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the form method to POST in your case. Try

```
<form action="create.php" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your form tag

```
method='post'
```

Answer (score 0):

Default method for form is GET, and you're trying to get your values from POST, so they're empty...

You should do:

```
$password = $_GET['password'];
// etc.
```

Or, if you don't know:

```
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider including `<form  action="create.php" autocomplete="on" method="POST">`

Please I beg you, Don't store raw password in database just use an encryption method.
And use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`

see here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: No, not md5. If you're going to recommend password hashing, do not even mention md5. Password hashing and md5 should not appear in the same sentence unless there is a "not" somewhere in it.

Comment: Why oh why do people ever think MD5 has anythign to do with passwords.please read the man page where it states it is NOT recommended to use it for passwords http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: maybe because 70% of passwords in databases all over the world are stored using md5 and maybe plus salt. The idea of md5 being useless is newly developed due to massive decryption of passwords recently, using broutfocers or rainbow tables.

Comment: @Youhan in the number of characters it took you to write "at least `md5`" with 6 more, you could have wrote "like password_hash()"

Comment: We don't recommend people start using mysql_* functions  any more so why would we recommend they start to use md5() for passwords when there are much better options that have been available for years.

Comment: Yeah right Anigel and Mike, I just edited the answer to avoid misguiding readers. Thank you!

Comment: I'll take into consideration this. As I mention, my CTO is the one who's going to give the final touches to the code, I just wanted to know how is it that everything works. But I'll definitely check PDO and MySQli and the password protection as you guys mentioned. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend you to use a mysqli class. I've used this one myself in smaller projects: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class
2. You're missing "form validation" in your code. This prevents empty and malicious form submits if you integrate validation properly into your forms and backend code
3. A simple example of how to make sure **data** was entered in the specific fields, try this:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['usernamesignup']), empty($_POST['...']))
{
    echo 'Not all required data was submitted';
}
else
{
    // Process the form, all data was received
}
```

4. Have you considered using a php framework? Try something like [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) if you want something more advanced and usable.